# If $ \lim_{x\to 0^+} f(x) = \lim_{x\to 0^+} g(x) = 1$ then $f(x) g(x) > 1$ for some $x$

Tags: real-analysis

Does the following hold?

> Let $f,g : (0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f$ is an increasing function and $g$ is a decreasing function satisfying $$ \lim_{x\to 0^+} f(x) = \lim_{x\to 0^+} g(x) = 1,$$ then there exists $x\in(0,\infty)$ such that $f(x) g(x) > 1$

I think it's true, and it  also looks like $f(x) g(x) < 1$ for some $x$.

I have tried to prove it using contradiction, assuming $f(x) g(x) \leq 1$ for all $x$, then stuck.

Any help (especially hint) would be very appreciated.

Comment: What about $f(x)=x+1$ and $g(x)=1/f(x)$?

Comment: If $f$ and $g$ aren't supposed to be strictly increasing/decreasing, then $f(x):=g(x):=1$ is a counterexample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Consider $f(x)=x+1$ and $g(x)=1/(x+1)^2$.